# TeamCity Deploy Build Output

Tags: asp.net, teamcity

I'm currently setting up CI for my project and have team city configure and running my builds (and tests etc).  However, what I can't seem to figure out is how to get it to actually deploy the build to my web-server.  I'm using the sln2008 runner if that help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCity doesn't support any deployment by itself. You can do it from a dependent build or as a part of your main build. There is a related issue that you can Watch/Vote: [TW-3746](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-3746).

Comment: I've switched to MSBuild so I can do this myself.

Comment: @Chris you can give more details? I had the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You can configure a web deploy step:

**IIS configuration**

- Follow the steps on this tutorial to configure the Web Deployment Handler on IIS: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/ (the database part could be ignore)

**TeamCity configuration**

- Add a new step:
- Field "Runner type" select "MSBuild"
- Field "Build file path" type the path to the web project. eg.:SRC\MyWebSite\MyWebSite.csproj
- Field "Command line parameteres" type "/P:Configuration=%env.Configuration% /P:DeployOnBuild=True /P:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /P:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://%env.TargetServer%/MsDeploy.axd /P:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /P:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC /P:UserName=WebDeploy /P:Password=WebDeploy /P:DeployIISAppPath= /P:CreatePackageOnPublish=True"
- Save it.
- Click on "Build Parameters"
- Field "env.Configuration" type the configuration you have used to compile solution: "Release" or "Debug".
- Field "env.TargetServer" the IIS server where the web deploy will be performed. Eg.:localhost:8172.

Run your build configuration.